# Can I add column to fullCalendar monthly view?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

As you can see I have **week total** column in the end of the calendar, meybe somebody knwo how I can add this?
[image]

I have try to do it manully just by adding custom componet near calendar, but I faced a lot of issue with sizing, because cell size is very on different factors and it's hard to calculate size which match in every case

Comment: You'd have to create a custom view for fullcalendar I expect. The documentation has a page describing the basics of setting up a custom view with your own code. After that you're largely on your own. Consider cloning the code of the existing day Grid view from the fullcalendar source code, to give you a starting point

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I did this another way, by creating a custom component and adjusting sizes by subscribing to row changes in the calendar.

Comment: Ah that's great. If you solved it, please consider adding your solution below in the Answer section, so that others with a similar problem could benefit from it (and will then give you upvotes!). See also [answer]. Thanks